# Browser History for Grails?

Tags: grails, browser-history

I'm working with my team to create an enterprise level web application with Grails, but I don't see any "out of the box" solution to dealing with browser history when using grails with AJAX.  Can someone point me to some documentation so that I can nail this?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: what do you mean by "History"

Comment: When you navigate from page to page, the browser keeps track of where you have been.  Javascript has a mechanism that lets you programatically insert items into the browser history when navigating without changing the URL, but I was wondering if Grails has some cool way of doing it easier and betterrer, integrating it with the view and/or the controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails is predominantly a server-side framework. All it provides in terms of client-side functionality are some tags to make it easy to call the server via AJAX. I'm not aware of any functionality in the core framework to support using the back/forward buttons when AJAX calls are made.

You might find something in a plugin, but I doubt it. Your best bet is to look for this functionality in whichever JS library you're using (YUI, JQuery, Dojo, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done by changing the `location.hash` property on the page.  This corresponds to a string you can add after the current url with a `#`.  Adding or modifying this part of the URL will keep you on the same page, but add an additional history entry.

The [jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) is a very useful framework to manage the hash.  It contains a number of useful methods to manage the hash property as key/value pairs, the same way the regular URL query string works.